# How do i read a XML file with namespaces (VB.net)

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

Ok, since my last question about this trouble was a bit faulty, i decided to make a new one that's more correct.

Im trying to read a XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"> 
  <AllThingsInThisDocument> 
    <Headerstuff>
    </Headerstuff>
    <Reports>
      <Report>
        <Id>01</Id>
        <Name>AA</Name>
      </Report>
      <Report>
        <Id>02</Id>
        <Name>BB</Name>
      </Report>
    </Reports>
  </AllThingsInThisDocument>
</Document>
```

when i use this code to loop the reports, it gives me no errors but it gives me null;

```
Dim xmlr As XDocument = XDocument.Load("MyMxlFile.xml")
For Each report As XElement In xmlr.Descendants("Report")
   'Do some cool stuff
Next
```

I have found out that it's the `xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"` that gives me the error. If i remove this from the xmlfile, it gives me the reports.

Just for test, I've tried with two functions, one that removes all namespaces and one that sets them to blank. I ran these function before looping. This works, but gives me an error about the namespace when i try to save it as a new xml file. And it really feels like the wrong way of doing this.

How can i read these reports with this namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim df As XNamespace = xmlr.Root.Name.Namespace

For Each report As XElement In xmlr.Descendants(df + "Report")
  Console.WriteLine(report.Element(df + "Name").Value)
Next
```